# Replce the URL with the variable

Tags: php, html, facebook, hyperlink

```
<input type="button" 
    style="height: 40px; width: 185px; background-color:#4863A0;
           Color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold; text-align:center" 
    value="Login using facebook" 
    onClick="parent.location='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=256953694326584&redirect_uri=**http://www.juboapp.com/**edit.php&scope=email,user_birthday,offline_access'">
```

Here we need to replace the url "http://www.juboapp.com/" with the variable which store this link. This variable comes from another PHP file.

How can i replace this link with this variable, so that it can redirect on the given link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable and store url in it. and use the following:

```
$dynamicUrl = "http://www.google.com/";

<input type="button" style="height: 40px; width: 185px; background-color:#4863A0;

 Color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold; text-align:center" value="Login using facebook" 

onClick="parent.location='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&

client_id=256953694326584&redirect_uri=<?php echo $dynamicUrl?>edit.php&

scope=email,user_birthday,offline_access'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Its nice and simple, replace:

`http://www.juboapp.com/` with `<?php echo $yourvariable; ?>`

However, if the variable is established in another script (script A) you need for it to be readable by the script you want to replace the URL in (script B)- you either need to [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the first script (script A) in the second (script B), or on your other script (script A) assign the variable to a session or cookie.